# Disable timeout function if div is no longer visible - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of intro screens showing before getting into the main content of the page. These scroll down automatically and disappear when moved on to the next section. I have managed to make the functionality work, but I run into an issue when, if you don't wait and just scroll down quickly, the timeout function of the intro screens is still running in the background, making the page jump up unnecessarily (as the intro screens are already hidden at this point).

I don't really know JS and I have tried to put this together with extensive trial and error. Basically now I am unable to change the JS to only run the auto-scroll when the intro is still visible - and not run it if it isn't.

I've included a working example and added comments where I think the auto-scroll code should possibly go to avoid the issue? Of course I have tried to paste the code into that section and doesn't work, I think it needs to be written differently and that's where I hope somebody can help me implement this. Many thanks in advance.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var $test = document.getElementById('toHide'),
    $tOffset = $test.offsetTop,
    $tHeight = $test.clientHeight,
    $winH = window.innerHeight,
    $scrollY;
    
    $scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if($scrollY > ($tOffset + $tHeight)){
        $test.classList.add('hiddenByScroll');
    // add here clearTimeout ?
    }
    if($scrollY < ($tOffset + $tHeight)){
    // add here setTimeout ?    
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
  var anchor1 = document.querySelector('#scrollUp1');

  anchor1.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
  var anchor2 = document.querySelector('#scrollUp2');

  anchor2.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}, 6000);
```

```css
#intro {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
#scrollUp1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
}
#scrollUp2 {
  background: black;
  height: 900px;
}
#toHide.hiddenByScroll {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="toHide">
  <div id="intro"></div>
  <div id="scrollUp1"></div>
</div>
<div id="scrollUp2"></div>
```

Comment: `// add here clearTimeout ?` why not try just that? `let tId1 = setTimeout ... let tId2 = setTimeout ... clearTimeout(tId1);clearTimeout(tId2);`